# Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: virtualbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64PqR.png)

When I press "try or install ubuntu" which is the first option in VirtualBox, it shows this message. I'm trying it on windows 11.

Comment: How much RAM did you allocate to the VM?

Comment: Is the option to use VM enabled in the UEFI ( what some people incorrectly still call BIOS )?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)